# Can I customize the check mark position in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm working on a UITable with allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true, then I get a circle and red checkmark in the table when it is editing:

[image]

The problem is, I need to customize the table view cell such that there are some background image for the cell, and I need a larger margin in the left side of the cell. I can customize the cell contentView for the content position, but are there a way I can **customize the checkmark and circle position**?

I could have implement a customize table view cell with my own multi selection logic and view, but are there a way I can do it with the built-in multi-select implementation? If not, would you recommend a idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, you cannot move the red checkmark and circle (editing control) with public API.

You can however, override the **UITableViewCell layoutSubviews** method. Inside it find the subview which is a "**UITableViewCellEditControl**", and modify its position as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I had one cell that didn't need to the check mark and the only way to do it was hide it from layoutSubviews as you mentioned. No need for includes, i just checked for existence using NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellEditControl");

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to change the position of the check mark,

Please make a Table View cell XIB and give it a background image  and check mark image and a label ..

the hiding and the display of the check mark will be managed by the associated class of XIB.

it will work for you.

** All the best

Comment: Thanks. But this probably will not work as I'm not customizing accessoryView, backgroundView, editingAccessoryView nor selectedBackgroundView.

Comment: if you want to relocate the accessory view it is a read only subview of a uitablevierw cell so it is not possible to relocate it.

Comment: Have a look at the screenshots, what I want to relocate is the "Red" checkmark and circle on the left, not accessory view (which is on the right)